# Только начинаю программировать и не могу понять почему не работает код; что значит ошибка компиллятора. Предложите такой же код с исправлением

Tags: java

[image: код должен работать таким способом]

Ошибка компиллятора

```
error: '(' expected
    public static void String main alle(String[] args)
```

Comment: Как-то странно, что в ошибке у вас другой код, чем приведённый вами. А вообще `main` - это название основной функции программы, после него должна быть скобка и аргументы. А у вас через пробел ещё одно слово идёт.

Comment: Исправил на public void String MainAlle(String a, String b) { компилятор все равно ругается с той же ошибкой

Comment: Вы файл то не забываете сохранять, прежде чем компилировать? То, что у вас в ошибке другой код программы, как бы намекает.

Answer (score 2):

1. Main функция должна иметь следующий вид:

   `public static void main(String[] args)`
2. Функция возврата, в ней ошибки. У вас не объявлен тип переменных a и b, должно быть что-то вида `String a = "12345678"`
   Также нельзя делать подряд два `return`, будет ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Имя метода нельзя писать через пробел и исходя из устоявшихся правил именование в Java, метод нужно назвать *MainAlle*, а лучше что-то более информативное и начинающееся с глагола(действия), например *ConcatenateStrings* или сокращённо *ConcateStrings*

Comment: Исправил на public void String MainAlle(String a, String b) { компилятор все равно ругается с той же ошибкой

Comment: @System.out.println "void String" не бывает, бывает либо "void", либо "String", либо что-то ещё. Правильно будет public void MainAlle(String a, String b).